# Draw overlapping ellipses (Venn diagrams) in latex (Set theory)

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks, asymptote, draw

[image]

Hi. How can I draw those multiple choice in latex?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Very good image and for my humble opinion. I have upvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the wrong tags.

Comment: Don't worry :-) I hope they're correct. But surely you can solve your question in other ways too.

Comment: I  thought of drawing the ellipses in photoshop and  add the imagem but i want to know if there is an easiest way

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item $\Circled{~\alpha\vphantom{\beta}~}\hspace{-1ex}\Circled{~\beta~}$
 \item $\Circled{~\alpha~\Circled{\beta}~}$
 \item $\Circled{~\beta~\Circled{\alpha}~}$
 \item $\Circled{~\alpha\vphantom{\beta}~}\,\Circled{~\beta~}$
 \item $\Circled{~\alpha\equiv\beta~}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
 \task $\Circled{~\alpha\vphantom{\beta}~}\hspace{-1ex}\Circled{~\beta~}$
 \task $\Circled{~\alpha~\Circled{\beta}~}$
 \task $\Circled{~\beta~\Circled{\alpha}~}$
 \task $\Circled{~\alpha\vphantom{\beta}~}\,\Circled{~\beta~}$
 \task $\Circled{~\alpha\equiv\beta~}$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have real ellipses, use Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\tikzset{elli/.style={ellipse,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep=1pt,draw,execute at
begin node={\vphantom{$\beta$}}}}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
 \task \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(alpha.base)}]
   \node[elli](alpha){$\alpha$}; 
   \node[base right=-1ex of alpha,elli](beta){$\beta$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \task \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(alpha.base)}]
   \node(alpha){$\alpha$}; 
   \node[base right=1ex of alpha,elli](beta){$\beta$};
   \node[draw,fit=(alpha)(beta),elli]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \task \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(alpha.base)}]
   \node[elli](alpha){$\alpha$}; 
   \node[base left=1ex of alpha](beta){$\beta$};
   \node[draw,fit=(alpha)(beta),elli]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \task \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(alpha.base)}]
   \node[elli](alpha){$\alpha$}; 
   \node[base right=1ex of alpha,elli](beta){$\beta$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \task \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(alpha.base)}]
   \node[elli](alpha){$\alpha\equiv\beta$}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. But more ovals can't you get?

Comment: @Sebastiano What do you mean by that?

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks. I will study that code

Comment: I hope the translator translates well. Your code is perfect, but they're not true ellipses. Doesn't the package you use include ovals with appropriate modifications?

Comment: @Sebastiano I am not sure you can get it with `circledsteps`. You certainly can get it with `tikz`. I added an example. (While I generally like to have fancy presentations of things, I feel that in this case having true ellipses does not add too much information.)